# how i can generate arandom password with this filter woocommerce

Tags: wordpress

thanks for help me. 
Then, i try a generate a random password with this code, but at present generate a date.
I neet generate a random password.

thanks

```
function changePassword($pass) {
        $password = date('Y');
        return $password;
}
add_filter('random_password', 'changePassword');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
function changePassword( $pass ) {
    return wp_generate_password();
}
add_filter( 'random_password', 'changePassword' );
```

Hope it's help you. Check please the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/).